# Word Macro 2010 for counting highlights

Tags: highlight

I want to know if this can be done? I just want to count the certain highlighted group of words.. not by word by word but by how many highlights does it have.. then will output the number of highlighted items..
Please help me.. Just imagine that the ones that have quotations have colors on it. Hope someone could help me..

Legends: "Red marks" = Wrong spelling and punctuations – Example: "dont, ternd mirco"

5 or more entries of wrong spelled words and punctuations will make your score cards

```
 "Yellow Highlights" = incorrect grammars - Example: "Do you sure?"
```

2 or more entries of incorrect grammars will make your score cards

```
 "Green Highlights" = inappropriate sentence structure – Example: "Insert CD to USB."
```

2 or more entries of incorrect sentence structure will make your score cards

There are 2 Red Highlights
There are 2 Yellow Highlights
There are 2 Green Highlights